# Can i write txt file into data\data\com.example.app(other app)\files without root?

Tags: java, android

Can i write a .txt file into data\data\com.example.app(other app)\files without root in android.

Comment: Why do you want this? Is the other app developed by you?

Comment: Yes, the other app is developed by me

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that. See [System Permissions | User IDs and File Access](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html#userid)

> Because security enforcement happens at the process level, the code of any two packages cannot normally run in the same process, since they need to run as different Linux users. You can use the sharedUserId attribute in the AndroidManifest.xml's manifest tag of each package to have them assigned the same user ID. By doing this, for purposes of security the two packages are then treated as being the same application, with the same user ID and file permissions. Note that in order to retain security, only two applications signed with the same signature (and requesting the same sharedUserId) will be given the same user ID.